# xaml telerik won't resolve RadGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, telerik, visual-studio-2012

Intellisense in Visual Studio for some reason isn't picking up telerik RadGridView.

My project is targeting .NET 3.5 and has the following references:

`Telerik.Windows.Controls`

`Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView`

`Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input`

`Telerik.Windows.Data`

All of these are for .NET 3.5 and have a runtime version of 2.0.X

My code:

```
<Window x:Class="Project.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
    <StackPanel>
        <telerik:RadGridView></telerik:RadGridView> <-- this won't resolve
```

Forum posts on telerik don't have anything I don't already have here.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?